# How to check multiple function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I have many functions written in JavaScript such as `userName()`, `password()` etc. But on submitting on the form, I have a single function `return formValidator();`.

I want function to call all the other functions and check whether they are returning false or not. If they all are true than it should return true, otherwise it should return false.

```
function userName(){
      var x=document.forms["signupform"]["firstname"].value;
            if(x=="" ||x==null){
           document.getElementById("firstname").style.border="1px solid #F50A0A";
           document.getElementById("firstname").style.boxShadow="2px 2px 5px #F50A0A";
           return false;
      }else {return true;}
}

function password(){
 var z=document.forms["signupform"]["password"].value;
      if(z=="" ||z==null){
            document.getElementById("password").style.border="1px solid #F50A0A";
           document.getElementById("password").style.boxShadow="2px 2px 5px #F50A0A";
            return false;
      }else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call each function, using the `&&` operator to indicate that each one must return something that evaluates to `true`. If any one of them returns something that evaluates to `false`, the entire statement will evaluate to `false`:

```
function formValidator() {
    return userName() && password() && somethingElse() && etc();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1):

```
var validators = [userName, password, ...];
function formValidator() {
    return validators.every(function(fn){return fn();});
}
```

or just use the [AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
function formValidator() {
    return userName() && password() && ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
function formValidator()
{
    var username = userName();
    var password = password();

    return username && password; // or just return userName() && password();
}
```

Comment: `if( condition_which_returns_boolean_true_or_false ) { return true` is redundant. just return the condition evaluation.

Comment: yes it is, I just wanted you to update it to remove the redundancy. I am not one of the downvoters.